# Using sqoop import, How to append rows into existing hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

From SQL server I imported and created a hive table using the below query.

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.1.12;database=testdb' --username uname --password paswd --table demotable --hive-import --hive-table hivedb.demotable --create-hive-table --fields-terminated-by ','
```

Command was successful, imported the data and created a table with 10000 records.

I inserted 10 new records in SQL server and tried to append these 10 records into existing hive table using --where clause

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.1.12;database=testdb' --username uname --password paswd --table demotable --where "ID > 10000" --hive-import -hive-table hivedb.demotable
```

But the sqoop job is getting failed with error

> ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!

Where am I going wrong? any other alternatives to insert into table using sqoop.

**EDIT:**
After slightly changing the above command I am able to append the new rows.

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.1.12;database=testdb' --username uname --password paswd --table demotable --where "ID > 10000" --hive-import -hive-table hivedb.demotable --fields-terminated-by ',' -m 1
```

Though it resolves the mentioned problem, I can't insert the modified rows. Is there any way to insert the modified rows without using
**--incremental lastmodified** parameter.

Comment: Could you pls run with --verbose and get proper error message.?

Answer (score 2):

in order to append rows to hive table, use the same query you have been using before, just remove the --hive-overwrite.

I will share the 2 queries that I used to import in hive, one for overwriting and one for append, you can use the same for importing:

To OVERWRITE the previous records

```
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=default --connect     jdbc:teradata://database_connection_string/DATABASE=database_name,TMODE=ANSI,LOGMECH=LDAP --username z****** --password ******* --query "select * from ****** where \$CONDITIONS" --split-by "HASHBUCKET(HASHROW(key to split)) MOD 4" --num-mappers 4 --hive-table hive_table_name --boundary-query "select 0, 3 from dbc.dbcinfo" --target-dir directory_name  --delete-target-dir --hive-import --hive-overwrite --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
```

TO APPEND to the previous records

```
 sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=default --connect jdbc:teradata://connection_string/DATABASE=db_name,TMODE=ANSI,LOGMECH=LDAP --username ****** --password ******--query "select * from **** where \$CONDITIONS" --split-by "HASHBUCKET(HASHROW(key to split)) MOD 4" --num-mappers 4 --hive-import --hive-table guestblock.prodrptgstrgtn --boundary-query "select 0, 3 from dbc.dbcinfo" --target-dir directory_name  --delete-target-dir --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
```

Note that I am using 4 mappers, you can use more as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can give direct --append option in sqoop with --hive-import option. Its still not available atleast in version 1.4.

The default behavior is append when --hive-overwrite and --create-hive-table is missing. (atleast in this context.

I go with nakulchawla09's answer. Though remind yourself to keep the --split-by option . This will ensure the split names in hive data store is appropriately created. otherwise you will not like the default naming. You can ignore this comment in case you don't care for the backstage hive warehouse naming and backstage data store. When i tried with the below command

**Before the append**

```
beeline:hive2> select count(*) from geolocation;

+-------+--+
|  _c0  |
+-------+--+
| 8000  |
+-------+--+
```

**file in hive warehouse before the append**

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root hdfs     479218 2018-10-12 11:03 /apps/hive/warehouse/geolocation/part-m-00000
```

**sqoop command for appending additional 8k records again**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/RAWDATA --table geolocation --username root --password hadoop --target-dir /rawdata --hive-import  --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --m 1 --delete-target-dir
```

it created the below files. You can see the file name is not great because did not give a split by option or split hash (can be datetime or date).

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root hdfs     479218 2018-10-12 11:03 /apps/hive/warehouse/geolocation/part-m-00000
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root hdfs     479218 2018-10-12 11:10 /apps/hive/warehouse/geolocation/part-m-00000_copy_1
```

**hive records appended now**

beeline:hive2> select count(*) from geolocation;

```
+-------+--+
|  _c0  |
+-------+--+
| 16000  |
+-------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this command:

```
 sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.1.12;database=testdb' --username uname --password paswd --query 'select * from demotable where ID > 10000' --hive-import --hive-table hivedb.demotable --target-dir demotable_data
```

Comment: I tried your command
i got the below error
**"Must specify destination with --target-dir."**

Comment: But with --hive-import --hive-table it would directly create a table in /user/hive/warehouse/ right? Ok i will try that.

Comment: madhu: I update the description. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--append` option and `-m 1` so it will be like below :

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.1.12;database=testdb' --username uname --password paswd --table demotable --hive-import --hive-table hivedb.demotable --append -m 1
```