# Sqoop import statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, sqoop

The below mentioned sqoop import statements worked for me the other day and today the same statements is showing error. Below is the error and import statement.

ERROR:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sqoop import

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre \
--username training --password training \
--table device \
-- target-dir /loudacre/device
-m 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `where $CONDITIONS'` in your import command. `where $CONDITIONS'` is mandatory and `$CONDITIONS` should be in upper case. Pls do this correction and try again.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed "\" at the end of fourth line:

can you run this and check it once.

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre \
--username training --password training \
--table device \
--target-dir /loudacre/device \
-m 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may face the error saying that --target-dir /loudacre/device already exists. when you run the command for the first as there is no target-dir defined in hdfs the script runs fine but for the second time as target-dir is already available in hdfs dir it throws error saying dir already exists.

Solutions to resolve this error:
1. Give another new directory or delete existing directory and try script again.
2. you can also import mysql data in sqoop append mode or overwride mode. Refer the below link for reference:
[Using sqoop import, How to append rows into existing hive table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885590/using-sqoop-import-how-to-append-rows-into-existing-hive-table)

Kindly let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Error solved guys. Turns out when you copy paste the command from notepad to terminal, " changes and results into an error.We need to explicitly write " in the temrinal.